# how to use an object of a class within that same class?

Tags: programming, data-type

I want to write a tree data structure made up of Nodes, but I'm having a problem with my Node.h class as each Node need to have a reference Variable to other Nodes,it's children. which ends up giving me the following error

> "field 'child' has incomplete type"

so I thought to myself if I was to `#include "Node.h"` within my Node.h class which gave another error

> "#include nested too deeply

how can I have reference to my child Nodes within my node class

Comment: With a forward declaration.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to c++ so i didn't know that . anyways, i define my child node as Node* child; is this correct?

Comment: Yes node* is a pointer.  Always make sure you initialise a pointer to NULL though, and check to see if it is NULL before you do anything to it.
And don't forget to free the memory when you have finished with it.  And never mix new/malloc and delete/free

Answer (score 0):

You will need to forward declare the class and add a pointer to it from within  the class.  i.e.

```
class CElement;  // Forward declaration

class CElement
{
public:
    CElement();
    ... // Other functions
private:
    CElement *m_NextElement;
};
```

Just to be clear you can't have your class as a member variable, it has to be a pointer or a reference.  This is because:

1. You can't use a type that hasn't been fully defined.
2. You would end up with your class consuming an infinite amount of memory, because every node would contain a node, which contains a node, etc...

Comment: You don't actually need to pre-declare the class the way you did on your first line: the class `CElement` is known about by the time the compiler gets to the `CElement *m_NextElement;` line

Comment: Also, check your "Just to be clear" line: you say "you can have your class as a member variable" - you mean "you _can't_". If you want you can have it as a reference - you imply you can't.

Comment: @Matt thanks, I added the forward declaration to my Node class. while i did manage to solve this I'm having a lot of trouble understanding when to use * or -> and new keyWord

Comment: @JohnBurger - Thanks, good spot.  My fingers were traveling faster than my brain.  Hopefully corrected them now.

Comment: @Matt Why do you think you can't have it as a reference? It may not be _useful_ (in this instance), but it's certainly legal.

Comment: @Raed Its difficult to guess your code, but assuming this is a simple class, I don't think you need to use a * except in the declaration of variables where it declares a pointer.  In the code *pointer will give you the data that is pointed to by pointer, which you can access with ->.  You use new to allocate memory CElement* pNewObject = new CElement(); and delete pNewObject should be all you need.  However I would recommend that you check that pNewObject has been allocated after the new and before the delete calls.  if (!pNewObject) // If not allocated report error.

Comment: @Raed: About "understanding when to use * or ->": `*pointer` means the thing `pointer` points to. It could be a simple entity like a number, or a whole bunch (tech term, heh) of entities like an array or a struct or a class. `pointer->foo` means the member named `foo` within the thing `pointer` points to. (In this case the "thing" would have to be a struct, a union, or a class, to have named members).

Answer (score 0):

#### If you have a class like this:

```
class Node {

public: // Methods

    inline Node() :
           left(nullptr),   // No children yet!
           right(nullptr) {
    } // Node()

public: // Variables (normally this should be private, but for this example...)

    Node *left;
    Node *right;

}; // Node

Node root; // The root of the tree
```

You now have a `class` that has two members, both pointers to `Node`s. Obviously there's going to be more data in there - `string`s or whatever - but let's ignore that for now.

I've also created the `root` of the tree - note that I didn't use `new`! It's a file variable that is always accessible, and there's not an `*` in sight (except inside `root`...).

What are `left` and `right`? Pointers to the children. They are ***not*** the children: just pointers to them. As soon as any `Node` is created (after the constructor has finished), the `Node` has no children - both pointers are `nullptr`.

So (ignoring any attempt to sort the children into place) you *could* now do the following:

```
void AddChildren() {
    Node sister;           // Create a sister
    Node brother;          // Create a brother
    root.left = &sister;   // Point to sister
    root.right = &brother; // Point to brother
} // AddChildren()
```

Note you couldn't do `node.left = sister;` - you're not trying to put `sister` *inside* `root`, you're only trying to *point* to `sister` *with* one of `root`'s children. So you take `sister`'s address with the `&` operator.

Only... as soon as `AddChildren()` exits, both `sister` and `brother` are destroyed (they're local to the function, so get destroyed as the function leaves) - but `root` is still pointing to where they used to be! It doesn't know that they are dead!

That is why you call `new`. It creates the object on the heap rather than the stack, and the object stays around until explicitly destroyed with `delete`. Only, `new` returns a pointer to the object, not the object itself. So:

```
void AddChildren() {
    Node *sister = new Node();  // Point to new object on the heap
    Node *brother = new Node(); // Point to new object on the heap
    root.left = sister;         // Already a pointer! Just copy it
    root.right = brother;       // Already a pointer! Just copy it
} // AddChildren()
```

Or, perhaps easier:

```
void AddChildren() {
    root.left = new Node();  // Point to new object on the heap
    root.right = new Node(); // Point to new object on the heap
} // AddChildren()
```

Now, how do you access the different fields inside `Node`? It depends on whether you're accessing them through an object or through a pointer:

- Through an object?
  With `.`, like `root.left` above
- Through a pointer?
  Using `->`, such as `ptr->left`

So finally, how can you use it for real?

```
// TraverseTree is going to call a function that looks like this:
typedef void TraverseFn(const Node &node);

// Traverse a (sub)tree, calling the passed-in fn() on each Node.
void TraverseTree(Node *node, TraverseFn *fn) {
    if (node == nullptr) { // Nothing to traverse!
        return;
    } // if
    TraverseTree(node->left, fn);  // Trees love recursion!
    fn(*node);                     // Call the passed-in fn with node
    TraverseTree(node->right, fn); // More recursion!
} // TraverseTree(Node)
```

And you can call the above with:

```
// A function to print the contents of Node
void PrintNode(const Node &node);

// Traverse the whole Tree, from root, calling PrintNode at each Node
TraverseTree(&root, &PrintNode);
```

---

### Beware! Do not pass! Here be dragons!

(or at least pointers to member functions...)

Personally, I would have put `TraverseTree()` inside `Node`:

```
class Node {

public: // Methods to call with Traverse()

    // Print this Node
    void Print();

public: // Traverse

    // This is the type of the function that Traverse will call
    typedef void TraverseFn();

    // Note we're passing in a pointer-to-member-function!
    void Traverse(TraverseFn Node::*fn) {
        if (left != nullptr) {
            left->Traverse(fn);
        } // if
        (this->*)fn();
        if (right != nullptr) {
            right->Traverse(fn);
        } // if
    } // Traverse(fn)

}; // Node
```

If you do that, you'd print out the tree like this:

```
root.Traverse(&Node::Print);
```